# Regex for splitting strings into an array and replacing elements of the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

Am looking to grab the tags from a form and save them to an array of strings to loop over.  I would like the tags to be stripped of white spaces, # signs, and commas.

This is almost working, but `tagArraySplit[i].replace(/#/g, '');` does not strip the '#'..

```
var newTags = $( "#newTags" ).val();
console.log(newTags);
// regex split for one or more commas or spaces
// so that multiple consecutive spaces or a comma+space .. are not empty
var tagArraySplit = newTags.split(/[ ,]+/).filter(Boolean);
var tags = [];
for (i=0; i<tagArraySplit.length; i++)
{
    console.log(tagArraySplit[i]);
    tagArraySplit[i].trim;
    tagArraySplit[i].replace(/#/g, '');
    console.log('trimmed a tag');
    console.log(tagArraySplit[i]);
    tags.push(tagArraySplit[i]);
}
console.log(tags);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store return value of `String#replace` method:

```
tagArraySplit[i] = tagArraySplit[i].replace(/#/g, '');
```

Comment: @anubhava please could you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797093/regex-email-validation-that-allows-only-hyphens-in-the-middle-of-the-domain-and

Comment: Sure let me take a look.