# Regex: Email validation that allows only hyphens in the middle of the domain and top-level domain

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I know this is been asked tons of times before , but I haven't found anything that really meets all the conditions that an email address must meet to be considered valid.

Considering the following as  the structure of an email address :

```
part1@part2.part3.part4
```

- part1=username
- part2=domain
- part3 and part4 =top-level domain

These are all the conditions that must be met:

1. An email address must not accept white spaces
2. An email address must not end in a dot or a character other than a letter or a number
3. Only one @ sign is allowed
4. There can not be a special character before or after the at sign
5. There can not be a special character before or after the domain dot (the dot after part2 of the email address)
6. You can not enter two or more dots in a row in the username
7. In the domain , between @ and the dot, the characters that are next to the @ and the dot must be a letter or number, in the middle the only special character allowed is the hyphen.
8. The same in step 7 goes for the top-level domain(part 3 and part 4 or the email)

This is the regular expression I currently using :

```
^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,9})+)$
```

But it does not meet conditions :4,5,6,7 and 8

I'm just trying to figure out how to complement my regular expression and learn in the process.

## EDIT

### The only special characters allowed in the email address are : dots, hyphens,underscores and the at sign

**Here's a list of invalid emails**

mkyong – must contains “@” symbol

mkyong123@.com – domain can not start with dot “.”

mkyong()*@gmail.com – email’s is only allow character, digit, underscore and dash

mkyong@%*.com – email’s tld is only allow character and digit

mkyong..2002@gmail.com – double dots “.” are not allow

mkyong.@gmail.com – email’s last character can not end with dot “.”

mkyong@mkyong@gmail.com – double “@” is not allow

mkyong@gmail.com.1a -email’s tld which has two characters can not contains digit

**Valid:**

mkyong@yahoo.com

mkyong-100@yahoo.com

mkyong.100@yahoo.com

mkyong111@mkyong.com

mkyong-100@mkyong.net

mkyong.100@mkyong.com.au

mkyong@1.com

mkyong@gmail.com.com

mkyong-100@yahoo-test.com

Comment: `/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/g` from http://regexr.com/2rhq7

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: javascript. I also wanted to validate in the server with C# , but I think javascript will be more than enough

Comment: You asked for my help some time ago, can you please provide a set of valid and invalid email addresses that I can test my regex against. Thanks

Comment: @sshashank124 I added a few examples to my question, please take a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the best I have been able to do as per your list of valid and invalid email addresses:

```
^([\w-]|(?<!\.)\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9]([\w\-]+)((\.([a-zA-Z]){2,9})+)$
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/nD5fC9)

Updated:

```
^([\w-]|(?<!\.)\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)((\.([a-zA-Z]){2,9}){0‌​,2})$
```

Comment: The domain still let me enter underscores so I have to change it to this: ^([\w-]|(?<!\.)\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)((\.([a-zA-Z]){2,9}){0,2})$  Please update your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Just the last question. Would it be possible allow hyphens in the middle of the the tld. That's what the condition 8 says, that is a minimum of 2 characters(only letter or number). If there's more than 2 characters only hyphens are allowed in the middle

Comment: Examples : aaa@bbb.co.pe (only 2 characters in the tld) | bbb@bbb.c-c.p-e (more than 2 characters in the tld, hyphen allowed in the middle) | ccc@bbb.cd--d-d.pe-8-ee (more than 2 characters in the tld, hyphen allowed in the middle)

Comment: @sshashank124 I tried once to allow hyphens in the middle (but not in the extremes) of TLD's , but in the end I couldn't do it. Hope we find an answer here :)

Comment: @Axel, Sorry I was sleeping. Hope I'm not too late. Hope this delivers: http://regex101.com/r/qF0oO0

Comment: @eddy, I posted some links in the comments above. They solved the problem for the OP.

Comment: @sshashank124 Thanks. One question, do you think this regex could be use in c# too??

Comment: @eddy, I suppose so. Best bet would be to actually try it. :P

Comment: @sshashank124 Hi, I know it's been a long time, but I tried to use your regex in asp.net but I got this error : "SyntaxError: invalid quantifier". I checked your demo and I noticed that it doesn't work when I change the `Flavor` to JavaScript. I think the problem is this part : `(?<!\.)` . Do you think you could give me a hand with it?

Comment: @eddy, I am not familiar with javascript so I may be wrong but a quick search revealed that javascript doesn't support `?<!` in its regex.

Answer (score 2):

> An email address must not accept white spaces

No, `"this is"@a-valid-e-mail-address.com`.

> Only one @ sign is allowed

No, `"this@is"@a-valid-e-mail-address.com`.

> There can not be a special character before or after the at sign

I’m not sure what this means, but it’s probably not true. `` !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}|~@example.org `` is perfectly fine.

> There can not be a special character before or after the domain dot (the dot after part2 of the email address)

`does@ţḩıš.çóûñţ`? Because it’s a valid e-mail address.

> You can not enter two or more dots in a row in the username

`can(...)too@localhost`

[Don’t use regular expressions to validate e-mail addresses, please.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/719543/707111)

Comment: I know that, but the only thing that I want and need is to find a way to meet all the conditions I listed in my question :(

Comment: @Axel: Why? In what situation would you want to match *almost* all valid e-mail addresses?

Comment: I never say I wanted to that. I'm just trying to make a regex for all the conditions listed in my question. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Email addresses do have a specific format that can be represented as a regular expression. The official format from [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4) is:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]      |  \\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@ (?:(?:a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?  |  \[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-]0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}       (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-]:          ?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

As indicated by [Jan Goyvaerts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33358/jan-goyvaerts), [regular expressions don't send emails](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) and therefore you can't actually know that it isn't valid until the email is sent and not received by the recipient.

Since you are tweaking the email regular expression in your own way, it doesn't make it right. It may answer your requirements to use that format, but email is fixed format and therefore just use the reference one, or a simplified one such as those listed on the [Regular-Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) page. Otherwise, this question will never get answered to your exact requirements.

Comment: But my requirements are specific. I don't intend to get a regex for all the possible email addresses

Comment: But email address is a fixed format already? Why not use the standard one?

Comment: I know they're not. I don't use the standard because the standard doesn't do what I need the regex to do.