# regular expression replace multiple matching pattern with link

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text fields that contains one or multiple occurrence of some code like "XX00123" or "XX00456", for example,

```
The XX00123 is a sibling of XX00456 and parent of XX00789
```

I would like to use regex to replace each occurrence of the code thing with a link to it. The result of above example would be then,

```
The <A HREF='http://server.com/XX00123'>XX00123</A> is a sibling of <A HREF='http://server.com/XX00456'>XX00456</A> and parent of <A HREF='http://server.com/XX00789'>XX00789</A>
```

I think I could do it with

1. put the search result in an array,
2. if the array is not empty, construct the text string of the link for each element in the array,
3. do a loop to find each occurrence again and replace it with the link

But is there any way to do this regular expression just in one line with JavaScript and/or JQuery?

Comment: Is there any particular language you're doing this in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following here.

```
var result = str.replace(/\b(XX\d+)\b/gi, "<A HREF='http://server.com/$1'>$1</A>");
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/155500)

Comment: Please don't abuse the `kbd` tag.

Comment: @hwnd please could you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797093/regex-email-validation-that-allows-only-hyphens-in-the-middle-of-the-domain-and

Comment: @Axel What did you need?

Comment: I need to complement my regex so it meets all the 8 requirements listed in my question. As it is , only meets 3 :S

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
var re = /([X0-9]+)/gi; 
var result = str.replace(re, "<A HREF='http://server.com/$1'>$1</A>");
```

**[REGEX101](http://regex101.com/r/tF2nV8)**

The `regex` will match one or more `x` followed by numbers until a space or a non-numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

With the following code,

```
var result = str.replace(/(XX(\d{5}))/ig, "<A HREF='server.com/$2'>$1</A>");
```

The result would be,

```
The <A HREF='http://server.com/00123'>XX00123</A> is a sibling of <A HREF='http://server.com/00456'>XX00456</A> and parent of <A HREF='http://server.com/00789'>XX00789</A>
```

The $1 represents "(XX(\d{5}))" - the out side pair of parentheses, and the $2 represents "(\d{5})" - the inside pair of parentheses.