# RegEx in jQuery replace pattern with link on SharePoint list view of multiple line text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, sharepoint

This is a slightly different question than the [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797418) that I asked before.

I have a multiple line text field in plain text format in a SharePoint list, where I allow the users manually input comments. In the comments, the user would refer to codes like XX00123 multiple times, e.g. `The XX00123 is a sibling of XX03456 and parent of XX00009`.

The code starts always with `XX` followed by a five-digit number.

In the AllItems list view, I put some jQuery code in the CEWP (Content Editor Web Part), so that the codes can appear as links.

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(XX(\d{5}))/ig, "<A HREF='http://server.com/$2'>$1</A>"));
```

For a pattern like `XX00123`, the result should be,

```
<A HREF='http://server.com/00123'>XX00123</A>
```

I wonder if there's anyway to refine the regex expression, still keep it in one line, so that the result could be as below,

```
<A HREF='http://server.com/123'>XX00123</A>
```

that,

1. the leading `0` shall be removed in the HREF string.
2. `XX000123` shall be interpreted as `<A HREF='http://server.com/12>XX00012</A>3`, instead of `<A HREF='http://server.com/123>XX0000123</A>` - only the first 5 digits counts.
3. `XX123` shall not be replaced, as the number of digits is not 5.
4. `XX00000` shall not be replaced either.
5. `XX12345` shall be replaced with `<A HREF='http://server.com/12345>XX12345</A>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I get it working as you expected. Hope it helps.Check this

```
var rep = $("#codes").html().replace(/XX(\d{5})\w*/g, function (match, number){return parseInt(number);  } );
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ujjaldhar/PhP47/

Comment: Yes, you did it.Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Lets filter the string by

```
XX[0]{2}[\d]{3}
```

The sample input output of this expression is given below:
    XX00123    --->  XX00123
    XX001234   --->  XX00123
    XX123      --->  FALSE
    XX000123   --->  XX00012

So, Now you can just take the last 3 digit as substring of the returned result. Hope it helps.

but one thing I must ask. What about XX12356 ?

Comment: the code is not always 3 digits, it could be XX00001, XX00012, XX00123, XX01234 or XX12345. I modified the wording in the question.

Comment: yes, then lets try this algorithm.

1. variable a = your code;

2. remove first two digit from a; // removing XX from the code

3. check the number of characters of a. 
    if(length>=5) 
        go to 4
    else
       'No need to replace'

4. take first 5 characters from a

5. remove all leading 0s

Comment: The point is that I wonder if we can keep the regex  still in one line.

Comment: Yes, as you said, you can find the code using (XX(\d{5}). Now the question is how to filter the code as you expect i.e no leading 0s and till 5th position. I got you.

Comment: I updated the wording of the question again, thanks for the comments!

Comment: I tried the parseInt(), it didn't work with .replace() the way I expected. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaowei1972/zz5j4/). I would like to show the original text, e.g. `XX00123`, with the correct link embedded, instead of replacing the original text.

Comment: Your fiddle works with only one instance of the pattern. If you take the example of `Test XX00125 XX00013 Codes`, i.e. multiple patterns in the string, it wont work, or we have to use multiple line of codes.

Comment: Can't you edit the code for multiple codes? I thought I have solved your problem. please just simple changes will make your code working for all of the codes. Thanks

Comment: See this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gaowei1972/PhP47/3/). only the first pattern replaced, and incorrectly.

Comment: Test this one. Hope it will solve your problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/ujjaldhar/PhP47/

Comment: Brilliant! I did some simple [change](http://jsfiddle.net/gaowei1972/PhP47/16/), I think this is the result I expected. If you could re-post it as an answer, I would flag it as accepted answer so you get the credit. The two key for the answer are: A - the parseInt(), B - the inline function for getting the matches of the regEx. Many thanks!